Using IP weighting for confounder adjustment in a mestreg or streg survival model in stata
I'm performing a survival analysis using mestreg (multilevel) and comparison streg (single level) for time to admission (time_admit, status_admit). I want to adjust for age_group and sex as confounding and need to try using inverse probability weighting instead of standard adjustment. I cannot find a way of integrating IP weights into the mestreg or streg models. Can you help please?

I’m voting to close this question because it asks for coding advice and in effect a personal tutorial. Questions that are in essence How do I do X in Y? are not good fits for SO, which thrives on specific concise questions showing what code you have and posing some puzzle about it. You would be much better off on Statalist, but showing code with a reproducible example.
